# HTML tags itself printing in Scala HTML

Tags: playframework-2.0

```
@(mylist:List[_root_.api.controllers.main.livingOrganism])
@main("Welcome Play Template") {


                    <table style="width:100%" border="box" style="border: 1px solid #660066;"><tbody>
                      <tr>

                        <th style="background: #eceaeb; border-right: 1px solid #cccccc; padding: 5px;">Bird</th>
                        <th style="background: #eceaeb; border-right: 1px solid #cccccc; padding: 5px;">Animal</th>
                        <th style="background: #eceaeb; border-right: 1px solid #cccccc; padding: 5px;">Fish</th>
                         </tr>
                    @for(p <- rpHistory) {
                      <tr>

                        <td style="background:#D6FFFF;">@p.bird</td>
                        <td style="background:#D6FFFF;">@p.animal</td>
                        <td style="background:#D6FFFF;">@p.fish</td>
                        </tr>}
                    <tbody>
                    </table>
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Bird is printing <p>parrot</p>
Animal is printing <p>Dog</p>
fish is printng <p>StarFish</p>
```

why its printing `<br />` `<p></p>` along with the text

Comment: Please, format your question that suits better for understanding.

Comment: Two questions: 1. how did you check generated code - via inspector tool or by viewing the source code? 2. which version of Play 2 exactly?

Comment: 3-rd question, can you publish this code , i.e. on github?